# Unable to create multiple sheets in excel via for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am writing a code where I am iterating on multiple sheets of an input excel file. From the data collected by reading those sheets one by one, I create an output dataframe and need to write the output of each iteration in a new sheet of the same excel file. I have tried multiple ways but I am unable to create multiple sheets.

Can anyone please help with modifications on the below code which will help me achieve the desired output, thanks?

```
for sheet in sheets:
    <do calculations>
    <do manipulations>
    <do slicing>
    
    print("Writing Ouput Sheet " + sheet)
    file_name = 'Output.xlsx'
    df_output.to_excel(file_name) # To create a empty file
    # To create one sheet for each iteration
    with pd.ExcelWriter(file_name, engine="openpyxl", mode = 'a') as writer:
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet)
```

More info:

The issue I am facing with the above code is that it generates an excel file with 2 sheets, 1 having the empty Sheet1 and the other the last sheet name from the list of sheets. What I am expecting is that it should write each sheet output in a separate worksheet in the same excel file.

Comment: _I am unable to create multiple sheets_ - this is unclear, do you get any errors? Please elaborate further. Create [mre]. Check [ask].

Comment: I think you should try creating the file outside of the `for` loop

Comment: @buran I have added the error/issue details.

Comment: @PaulH Unfortunately i tried that, still same, writes only one single data in one single sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by changing the sequence of the code:

```
writer = ExcelWriter('Output.xlsx')
for sheet in all_sheets:
    <do calculations>
    <do manipulations>
    <do slicing>
    
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet)
writer.save()
```

This is basically because we want to write multiple sheets in the same file so the initialization or definition of the writer should be only done once.

However, in case, only one sheet is required to be written then the writer can be defined anywhere inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if `mode='a'` is supported by the engine. One way you can go around is to move the writer creation outside the for loop:

```
print("Writing Ouput Sheet " + sheet)
file_name = 'Output.xlsx'

# To create one sheet for each iteration
with pd.ExcelWriter(file_name, engine="openpyxl", mode = 'a') as writer:
    for sheet in sheets:
        <do calculations>
        <do manipulations>
        <do slicing>
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet)
```

**Note**: I realized that in your code, you rewrite the file every iteration with:

```
df_output.to_excel(file_name) # To create a empty file
```

Remove it and your code may work, which is then better as you don't need to open the file all the time.

Comment: I made the suggested changes but not sure why it's writing only the last iteration data in the one sheet instead there should be more than 1 sheet each with the respective data.

Comment: @RSM maybe all of the elements in the your `sheets` list are the same

Comment: @PaulH No No, I have tested this multiple times on different datasets, and dummy data sets too, doesn't work, not sure why. Do you have references where I can check further?

Comment: @RSM are you asking for a link to the pandas docs?